# How do I retrieve values from a filter query within a CosmosDb stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

I'm struggling to work out how to retrieve the property values from a filter query in a CosmosDb stored procedure. I'm sure this must be relatively simple, but just can't seem to find the right combination.

```
var result = __.chain()
    .filter(function(doc) {
    return doc.id ==="1stDocId";
})
.map(function(doc) {
   return {
        id: doc.id,
        propertyA: doc.propertyA
   };
})
.value();
if(!result.isAccepted) throw new Error("The call was not accepted");
```

Using the above code, or similar, I'm wanting to retrieve the value of propertyA, and then use it in a second query, and so on.
Using response.setBody to return the value of *result* at this point, I can see it is sat in an array, but can't work out the correct code to access it.
result[0].PropertyA, result[0][0].PropertyA don't work, can someone point me in the right direction?

I'm able to do this sort of thing using the queryDocuments function, but ultimately my stored procedure needs to execute 5 or 6 select statements, manipulating the retrieved values in between. Utilising nested callbacks seems very messy, and pretty confusing once you're a few levels deep. Is there a better way?
Thanks.

Comment: You want do nested query in one single stored procedure or you want to call stored procedure many times?

Comment: Yes, it'd be nested queries, except really I was was wanting to avoid the nesting, so multiple queries in the same stored procedure. The wish to avoid nesting is to avoid the situation later down the line in the stored procedure where I have something like: 'if (propertyB == 1) then variableC = 2; else variableC = <result of another query>. If everything has to be nested (as seems to be the case with queryDocuments callbacks) how do I reliably get the value of variableC when it may, or may not involve a query.

Answer (score 0):

Well I gave in, and wrote the procedure using nested callbacks and 'queryDocuments'. Since at one point my procedure requires a switch statement, which either performs a db lookup, or provides a hard value, I had to duplicate the rest of the queryDocument calls in the db lookup branch callback, which feels plain wrong.
However, whilst not being pretty, my stored procedure now works, returning the correct values in all cases.